# Identify a modern Titanic movie having vampires

Tags: story-identification, movie

Here are the details of the movie:

- The name of the movie was "Titanic". Plain simple "Titanic", but it can be slightly different because I have already googled a lot.
- The main actor was either producer or director of the movie. His name isn't in my mind.
- The movie had lots of comedy. For example, the orchestra continued to play underwater in the end making bubble sounds.
- The movie had two vampire girls. Originally there was only one, but she made another girl vampire and then they both killed lots of people on-board. That another girl was the one who participated in the naked painting (this movie made it a comedy and the scene didn't involve the main actress).
- The movie was 18+. It showed lots of boobs. Unlike original Titanic (which did that only once), vampire girls in this movie remained naked for a long time.
- Unlike the original Titanic, the main actor was rich who owned the ship.
- **The Plot:** A new unsinkable ship named "Titanic" was launched probably on the 100th anniversary of original ship sinking. This ship had advanced computer-based navigation, military-grade SONAR and even more than enough modern life boats. The ship was equipped with one helicopter, too. But, the history repeated itself (the quote exists in the movie) and this time they encountered hoards of icebergs victims of global warming (probably, there was a tsunami too). Large number of violent icebergs made life boats helpless. The main actor (who was owner or major investor of the ship) was told to escape using helicopter but he refused. He went on in search of main actress who was a low-pay ship staff. In the end, he found her. There was one Oxygen mask with him which he used on her and died gladly underwater.

Can you please identify the movie?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes, this made me smile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be [Scary Sexy Disaster Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212559/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt), released in 1999. It was also released as "Titanic 2000".

It involves the Titanic 2000's maiden voyage, with vampires as passengers.

The vampires are lesbians, and the movie contains a fair bit of nudity and sexual situations.

However, I cannot find any mention of the director also being a star of the movie.

[image]

From one of the [IMDB reviews](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212559/reviews):

> the year is 2000 and the titanic (excuse me, the TITanic as they call it in this soft-core flick) is being rebuilt for another doomed voyage from new york to england in this failure of spoof of the 1997 hit movie titanic with Leonardo Di caprio and Kate winslet. however, they had to make some changes in building the ship. for example, in order to have enough money to buy the captain is golden steering wheel, which ends up being stolen, they had to finish the ship in aluminum. in addition, all of the life boats had to be taken off the ship so the weight capacity can include a snotty rich man's car. in this film, there is also an unexpected passenger on board the ship, the sexy lesbian vampire vladima and her two henchman.

Comment: btw: this was the first search result when searching for "titanic vampire movie"